# How does the 'Publisher returns" happen/work in Spring AMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am working on RabbitMQ integration. I have a microservice which receives messages from other services. I am currently looking into how to handle messages which encounter exceptions during processing.

The scenario could be:

1. ServiceA sends message to engine's queue.
2. Engine processes the message received.
3. During processing, engine encountered an exception (say a NullPointerException)
4. Engine returns the message to ServiceA for reprocessing
5. ServiceA holds the message until the exception in the engine is resolved (resending to engine can be manually triggered)

I bumped into [Spring AMQP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#template-confirms) about Publisher Returns but I could not totally grasp the context. I would like to know how this works and if this could be a solution to address above item #4. Or is there other solution for this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #4 on your list the solution is quite simple - don't acknowledge the message automatically, rather then when the processing is finished. In that way - 
if the client (subscriber) dies (for whatever reason) during processing of the message then that message is re-queued (so sent to ServiceA for reprocessing in your case).

If you want to explicitly re-queue the message you could do **negative acknowledgment** (search for it [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)).

In any case of re-queuing (manual or automatic) you should **be careful** that the single message that causes subscribers to die doesn't end up being processed forever by subscriber(s), that is - make sure that the exception that happened during processing was a random and not a *guaranteed* event. Example for this would be a message containing invalid XML - you process it, see it's invalid, handle the exception and re-queue, but then again another (or the same) subscriber gets it, and handles the same exception since the **content** of the message and the XML inside it **didn't change** and so on...

Comment: thank you for your answer! I would like to add that I think when the engine throws an exception it is already considered as negative acknowledgement. I experience the repeated processing of the rejected message by the engine which is not ideal as it will fill up the logs especially if it is the only message in the queue. This is actually what I want to address. How could I send back the message to its source and let it hold the message until the cause of exception is addressed. Or is it even possible in the first place. Thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome! And since you are new: according to meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/… I guess I wouldn't seem to bad if I ask for upvote and accept :) As for the other thing (holding the message) I didn't fully understand the question, so please provide some more details - best in the new question, since it is a new question :)